# Use express-load in a modular mean project

Tags: mean-stack, meanjs, modular

I changed my project folder structure to use a modular approach where each functionality is grouped in folders inside "modules" directory (as defined at https://github.com/meanjs/mean).

e.g.:

[image: My project folder structure]

How can I define express-load, since now I have more than one root directory for my models, controllers and routes?

It was previously configured all in the app directory.

e.g.:

[image: Previous project folder structure]

```
load('models', {cwd: 'app'})
    .then('controllers')
    .then('routes')
    .into(app);
```